# Components under what licenses can I use in my paid app?

Tags: licensing, mit-license, bsd-license, apache-license

I'm working on an application and I need to use some existing components such as libraries and JavaScript frameworks that are covered by licenses. My application will be paid (not free) and closed-source.

Can I use components in my app that are under one of following licenses:

- MIT
- Apache
- BSD

Comment: Have you read the licenses? The MIT and BSD licenses are two or three paragraphs and the Apache license is maybe 2 pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) :

> It is a permissive license, meaning that it permits reuse within proprietary software provided all copies of the licensed software include a copy of the MIT License terms.

From [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License) :

> Like any free software license, the Apache License allows the user of the software the freedom to use the software for any purpose, to distribute it, to modify it, and to distribute modified versions of the software, under the terms of the license.

From [BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses) :

> The BSD License allows proprietary use, and for the software released under the license to be incorporated into proprietary products. Works based on the material may be released under a proprietary license or as closed source software.

So, the answer is : yes, you can use libraries with all 3 licences, but if you modify them, then take a look into licence details.